# How to vertically center widgets inside a table cell in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt

i added some widgets to QFormLayout then add this layout to cell in table but it seems the widgets are aligned to top and i want them to be centered vertically so they be in center, here is an image to explain :
[image]

the class of making the layout and its widgets:

```
class Options(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,row=[], ops=[]):
        super(Options, self).__init__(parent)
        self.i = random.randint(1, 100)
        self.row = [j.decode("utf-8") if i!=1 else "image" for i,j in enumerate(row)]
        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        ops = ast.literal_eval(ops[0]) if len(ops[0])>1 else {}
        for i,j in ops.items():
            #adding widgets here and it is not related!

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Submit")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.do)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment of the QFormLayout:

```
self.layout.setFormAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

<sub>It's usually better to avoid overwriting existing instance attributes: [`self.layout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout) is a default function for all QWidget descendants; you either use a local variable or a different name.</sub>